# why replacing *s with **s in SortedMerge() causes the program to crash?

Tags: c, linked-list, mergesort

while debugging i found that replacing **s by *s makes the program work correctly, but i dont understand why **s causes eroor in SortedMerge() function, please help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

/* function prototypes */
struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b);
void FrontBackSplit(struct node* source,
          struct node** frontRef, struct node** backRef);

/* sorts the linked list by changing next pointers (not data) */
void MergeSort(struct node **head)
{
    /*if list empty or contains one element, return head*/
    if((*head==NULL)||((*head)->next)==NULL)
        return *head;

    /*if control here, implies, atleast 2 nodes present in ll*/
    struct node* a=NULL;
    struct node* b=NULL;
    FrontBackSplit(*head,&a,&b);

    MergeSort(&a);
    MergeSort(&b);

    *head=SortedMerge(a,b);

}

/* See http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=3622 for details of this
   function */
struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* first,struct node* second)
{
    if((first==NULL)&&(second==NULL))
        return NULL;
    if(first==NULL)
        return (second);
    if(second==NULL)
    {
        return (first);
    }
    /*first and second list both have elements*/

    struct node **s=NULL;
    struct node *z=NULL;

    while((first!=NULL)&&(second!=NULL))
    {
        if(*s==NULL)
        {
            *s = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            z = *s;
        }
        else
        {
            z->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            z = z->next;
        }

        if(first->data<=second->data)
        {
            z->data = first->data;
            first = first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            z->data = second ->data;
            second = second ->next;
        }
    }
    while(first!=NULL)
    {
            z->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            z = z->next;

            z->data = first->data;
            first = first->next;
    }
    while(second!=NULL)
    {
            z->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            z = z->next;

            z->data = second->data;
            second = second->next;
    }
    z->next=NULL;
    return *s;
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Split the nodes of the given list into front and back halves,
     and return the two lists using the reference parameters.
     If the length is odd, the extra node should go in the front list.
     Uses the fast/slow pointer strategy.  */
void FrontBackSplit(struct node* head,struct node **first,struct node **last)
{
    struct node *slow_ptr=head;
    struct node *fast_ptr=head->next;
    if((head==NULL)||(head->next==NULL))
    {
        *first=head;
        *last=NULL;
        return;
    }

    while((fast_ptr!=NULL)&&(fast_ptr->next!=NULL))
    {
        fast_ptr=fast_ptr->next->next;
        slow_ptr=slow_ptr->next;
    }
    *last=slow_ptr->next;
    slow_ptr->next=NULL;
    *first=head;
    return;
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Split the nodes of the given list into front and back halves,
     and return the two lists using the reference parameters.
     If the length is odd, the extra node should go in the front list.
     Uses the fast/slow pointer strategy.  */


/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list */
void printList(struct node *node)
{
  while(node!=NULL)
  {
   printf("%d ", node->data);
   node = node->next;
  }
}

/* Function to insert a node at the beginging of the linked list */
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
  /* allocate node */
  struct node* new_node =
            (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  /* put in the data  */
  new_node->data  = new_data;

  /* link the old list off the new node */
  new_node->next = (*head_ref);

  /* move the head to point to the new node */
  (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

/* Drier program to test above functions*/
int main()
{
  /* Start with the empty list */
  struct node* res = NULL;
  struct node* a = NULL;

  /* Let us create a unsorted linked lists to test the functions
   Created lists shall be a: 2->3->20->5->10->15 */
  push(&a, 15);
  push(&a, 10);
  push(&a, 5);
  push(&a, 20);
  push(&a, 3);
  push(&a, 2);

  /* Sort the above created Linked List */
  MergeSort(&a);

  printf("\n Sorted Linked List is: \n");
  printList(a);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

here is the working SortedMerge() function, that i replaced..

```
struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b)
{
  struct node* result = NULL;

  /* Base cases */
  if (a == NULL)
     return(b);
  else if (b==NULL)
     return(a);

  /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
  if (a->data <= b->data)
  {
     result = a;
     result->next = SortedMerge(a->next, b);
  }
  else
  {
     result = b;
     result->next = SortedMerge(a, b->next);
  }
  return(result);
}
```

Comment: Not enough code for a running program to reproduce the problem. Too much code to read. Please try to either reduce to where you think the problem might be, or provide a compileable program.

Comment: You should also try to step through the program execution in a debugger to see where the infinite loop is occurring.

Comment: Why don't you try debugging?

Comment: of course i broke my head trying to find the bug,for over 2 hours, i couldnt that's why i posted it here.

Comment: @merlin2011 i have put the compilable code now, see the updated code

Comment: In merge you say `struct node **s=NULL;` and then the first time you reference s it is `if(*s==NULL)    /*adding first element to the unified list*/` which dereferences a NULL pointer.  And the program crashes and gdb shows what line it crashes on: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00000000004016e5 in merge (head=0x22fdd8, a=0x22fd98, b=0x22fd90) at a.cpp:95`

Comment: Have you tried gdb, it shows segmentation fault at line 95: if(*s==NULL)    /*adding first element to the unified list*/

Answer (score 0):

The `split` function divides the list into two pieces; no memory is allocated or freed. (Actually `*head` == `*a` after that, but that doesn't matter).

The `merge` function ought to be the inverse of `split`: combine two pieces into one list, without allocating or freeing. However it contains `malloc` statements. This must be an error; you should be merging the two lists by adjusting which element points to which next element.

It might be simpler to change your interface: just have `split(struct node **a, struct node **b)` that has pre-req `*b = NULL` and it moves half of `a`'s nodes to `b`; and then `merge(struct node **a, struct node **b);` that moves all of `b`'s nodes to `a`.

Comment: hi could you please have a look at the new piece of code that i put up